Schwarz-Pick Theorem Exercise
I am trying to solve the following problem, which I believe should be solved using the Schwarz-Pick Theorem.
Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disk and let $f\colon \mathbb{D}\xrightarrow{} \{z\in \mathbb{C} : e^{-\pi/2}<\vert z\vert< e^{\pi/2}\}$ be a holomorphic map satisfying $f(0) = 1$. Show that $\vert f'(0)\vert \leq 2$.
I tried to let $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{e^{\pi/2}}$ so that $g(\mathbb{D}) \subset \mathbb{D}$, but this only gave me $f'(0) \leq e^{\pi/2}-e^{-\pi/2}$. How can I get a better estimate? I was considering using a Mobius transformation $h$ whose image is contained in $\mathbb{D}$ and apply the theorem to $h\circ f$ but I don't know how to pick $h$.

I don't see how to use the Schwarz-Pick Theorem, but if I thought about it correctly it's indeed a consequence of the Lemma of Schwarz:
Since $f$ has no zeros and $f(0)=1$ there is a holomorphic logarithm $g \in H(\mathbb{D})$ such that $e^g=f$ on $\mathbb{D}$ and $g(0)=0$. Then
$$
\forall z \in \mathbb{D}: ~ \log(|f(z)|)=\Re g(z) \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2),
$$
and note that $f'(0)=e^{g(0)}g'(0)=g'(0)$.
So, $z \mapsto g(z)$ maps $\mathbb{D}$ to the strip $\{z:  \Re z \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)\}$, therefore
$z \mapsto e^{ig(z)}$ maps $\mathbb{D}$ to the right halfplane  $\mathbb{H}=\{z: \Re z > 0\}$, and the Möbiustransform $z \mapsto (z-1)/(z+1)$ maps $\mathbb{H}$ to $\mathbb{D}$. Thus
$$
h(z):= \frac{e^{ig(z)}-1}{e^{ig(z)}+1}
$$
maps $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$ with $h(0)=0$. By the Lemma of Schwarz
$$
1 \ge |h'(0)| = \left|\frac{2g'(0)i}{4}\right| = \frac{|g'(0)|}{2},
$$
hence $|f'(0)|=|g'(0)|\le 2$.
